# Melhor forma de receber date do "teclado"

Tags: java

Bom dia, Galerinha.

Preciso saber qual a melhor forma de armazenar datas em java.

Exemplo: Em uma classe clientes preciso receber a dataDeNascimento dos clientes, mas para isso preciso receber do teclado essa data. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Receber os dados de DIA MES e ANO separado seria uma boa maneira?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Sugiro que comece por fazer o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e ler o guia de [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Em relação à sua questão ela não ficou muito clara. Você fala em `date` mas o objetivo é utilizar um `java.util.date` ? ou `java.sql.date` ? ou nenhum desses ? E quando diz guardar refere-se a numa variável ou banco de dados ?

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer isso é receber dia, mês, ano e usar os dados para a setar um Gregorian Calendar.

Exemplo:

```
Scanner leitura = new Scanner(System.in); //Inicializa o leitor do teclado  

System.out.println("Digite o dia");  
int dia = leitura.nextInt(); // Ler do teclado e armazena na variavel dia   

System.out.println("Digite o mês"); 
int mes = leitura.nexInt; // Ler do teclado e armazena na variavel mês


System.out.println("Digite o ano"); 
int ano = leitura.nexInt;  // Ler do teclado e armazena na variavel ano 

GregorianCalendar dataDeNascimento = new GregorianCalendar();
dataDeNascimento.set(ano, mes-1, dia);  //Em GregorianCalendar os meses começam a partir do 0 e sim, ano é o primeiro a ser recebido.
```

Existem outras formas de fazer isso como por exemplo, usando Date, mas a maioria dos metodos da mesma estão descontinuados.

Costumo fazer da forma que eu mostrei acima para você e dependendo das operações que você for fazer, GregorianCalendar tem muitas funcionlidades como por exemplo obter a data em Millisegundos e coisas mais...

Caso queira ler mais: [DevMedia - JavaCalendar](https://www.devmedia.com.br/java-calendar-encapsulando-o-gregoriancalendar-com-um-datahelper/32108)

Comment: Dica: usar o LocalDate ao invés do GregorianCalendar :)

Comment: Siga a dica do @Dherik pois `GregorianCalendar` pode ser afetado por horário de verão e seu valor depende do timezone configurado na JVM. Já `LocalDate` não tem esses problemas (janeiro é 1 nesta API!) e é ideal se vc só precisa do dia, mês e ano. A partir do Java 8, use `java.time.LocalDate`, e para JDK 6 e 7, existe o [ThreeTen Backport](threeten.org/threetenbp), que possui a mesma classe, só que no pacote `org.threeten.bp`. Dê uma olhada no [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) para ver como o `java.time` funciona, é **muito** superior à `Calendar`.

Comment: Interessante! Obrigado pelas dicas mesmo a pergunta não sendo minha!

Answer (score 0):

Precisa ser necessariamente do teclado? Caso não, você pode usar o [JDatePicker](https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker). Caso precise, pode usar "dd/mm/aaaa".

```
Scanner s = new Scanner();
String[] raw = s.next().split("/");
int dia = raw[0];
int mes = raw[1];
int ano = raw[2];
```